# Writing CSV file from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Have a question. If I run this 
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RICot.png), I get exactly what I have in the [CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQgzu.png). My target is to get a text/data/csv file which would look like this:
['red', 'green', 'blue'] meaning:

1. Converting a single column into a row.
2. While converting to row, entering a comma to differentiate values.

Is it possible to do it through Python? Is there any online materials I can look into?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Since you are new, please check out [ask] and the [help]. Please make sure your questions are *self contained* as possible. Do not post links to code, do not use images of code, post the relevant code *in the question itself* as *formatted text*.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) is some info on formatting your code.

Comment: Interesting question.  It is very hard to help with code.  You need to post your code, not images of code.

Comment: _Is it possible to do it through Python?_ Yes. _Is there any online materials I can look into?_ That's explicitly off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

The csv file is read sequentially, that is, you will always get the data back one row at a time.  However, you can build an array of just the values you want as you read the file and discard the rest of the data.

```
import csv

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    colours = []
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
         if len(row) <= 3:
              continue
         colours.append(row[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this code using pandas. Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("input csv file")
df = df.T
df.to_csv("output csv file")
```

Update if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Without using any extra libraries, you could write a function that takes a specific column, and returns that column as an array.

Such a function might look like this.

```py
def column_to_row(col_num, csv):
    return list(row[col_num] for row in csv)
```

Then you can extract whatever column you want, or iterate through the whole csv like this.

```py
new_csv = []
for i in range(0, len(csv[0]):
    new_csv = new_csv.append(column_to_row(i, csv))
```

Comment: this won't exactly work with a `csv.reader` which is an iterator.